# How to make loop for list of object on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, list

Im getting ajax result as a list of objects and i need to display some result of finding text for every object in that list, every object its like other textarea, i found way how to make it for one textarea:

```
 success: function(data) {
    setTimeout("$('.loader').hide()", 2000);
    setTimeout("$('#lblack').hide()", 2000);
    console.log(data);

    var cheked_text;
    $.each(data[0].WordInfos, function(index, value) {
        if (value.q > 0) {
            var wr = value.w.fontcolor("red");
            cheked_text = text.replace(new RegExp(value.w, 'g'), '<b>' + wr + '</b>');
            text = cheked_text;
        }
    });
    var sub_ul = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(data[0].WordInfos, function(index, value) {
        var sub_li = $('<li/>');
        $(sub_li).html(value.w + "-" + value.q);
        $(sub_li).appendTo(sub_ul);
    });
    var exresult = document.getElementById("searchresult");
    var appendContent = $("<section id='searchresult'><h4>Result:</h4><div class='words'><b>Words:</b></div><div class='text'><b>Text:</b><br>" + text + "</div></section>");
    if (exresult == null) {
        $(appendContent).find(".words").append(sub_ul);
        $(".Results").append(appendContent);
    } else {
        $("#searchresult").html("<h4>Result:</h4><div class='words'>Words:</div><div class='text'>Text:<br>" + text + "</div>")
        $("#searchresult").find(".words").append(sub_ul);
    }
},
```

data - list of analyzeobjs object, my analyzeobj looks like:

```
   public class wordsinf
    {
        public string w;
        public int q;
        public wordsinf(string wf, int quan)
        {
            w = wf;
            q = quan;
        }
    }
    public class AnalyzeObj
    {
        public Guid id;
        public string text;
        public string[] FindWords;
        public List<wordsinf> WordInfos;
    }
```

So my example only works for a first object from list, i need to do the same with each of it and append like a another new Result, i tried already to put it all in an `$.each` for every data but it dont work, any ideas? Ask any questions if its not understandable a little.

Example of data output:

```
Array[2]
0:
Object
FindWords:
Array[2]
0:"asd"
1:"qwe"
WordInfos:
Array[2]
0:Object
q:1
w:"asd"
1:Object
q:2
w:"qwe"
id:"5d6621aa-74c6-496e-b57a-174426cc6b03"
text:"qweqwe asd ldalldsl"
```

[image: Thats how looks like result for one textarea.]

Comment: provide `data` output

Comment: thanks for edits,added example of data output.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

```
                       setTimeout("$('.loader').hide()", 2000);
                    setTimeout("$('#lblack').hide()", 2000);
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        var cheked_text;
                        var Edit_text = value.text;
                        $.each(value.WordInfos, function (index, value) {
                            if (value.q > 0) {
                                var wr = value.w.fontcolor("red");
                                cheked_text = Edit_text.replace(new RegExp(value.w, 'g'), '<b>' + wr + '</b>');
                                Edit_text = cheked_text;
                            }
                        });
                        var sub_ul = $('<ul/>');
                        $.each(value.WordInfos, function (index, value) {
                            var sub_li = $('<li/>');
                            $(sub_li).html(value.w + "-" + value.q);
                            $(sub_li).appendTo(sub_ul);
                        });
                        var exresult = document.getElementById("searchresult");
                        var appendContent = $("<section id='searchresult'><h4>Result:</h4><div class='words'><b>Words:</b></div><div class='text'><b>Text:</b><br>" + Edit_text + "</div></section>");

                            $(appendContent).find(".words").append(sub_ul);
                            $(".Results").append(appendContent);

                    });
```